# Using CSS to wrap text around image and have it behave like a background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, shape-outside

I'm using shape-outside to give a "magazine" feel to a website. Each page has a new image of a person and the text wraps around that person. Shape outside works perfectly and easy! Only issue is that I can't figure out how to make it so the text in one column (left) sets the height not the image (right).

Take this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/kvzmw0sy/22/

Or the raw code

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dq6tqnvbh/image/upload/v1552834755/5a366dd97df550.5130252915135165055159.png">
  <div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum rhoncus orci nec iaculis. Cras tempor aliquam sem, id accumsan nibh mollis nec. Sed eget dui pulvinar, iaculis nibh vitae, molestie metus. Aliquam tortor leo, laoreet a felis quis, ultricies dignissim mauris. Etiam quis consectetur nibh. In sodales et ex at malesuada. Phasellus et arcu eleifend, interdum ex eu, bibendum magna. 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
  float: right;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  shape-outside: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dq6tqnvbh/image/upload/v1552834755/5a366dd97df550.5130252915135165055159.png);

}
.footer {
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  border: 2px solid green
}
```

What I get is this:

[image]

But, what I want is this (see how the image goes behind the footer):

[image]

Essentially I want it to work like a background image.

I tried position absolute but it breaks the text wrapping. I don't think i can do this with a background image. And so the only solution I have so far is to use JS to get the height on the left and apply it to the container with an `overflow:hidden` which I'd really like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the new [`overflow:clip`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_overflow_clip) applied to the container will do the job

```css
.image {
  float: right;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  shape-outside: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dq6tqnvbh/image/upload/v1552834755/5a366dd97df550.5130252915135165055159.png);
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid green
}


/* .text{ 
shape-outside: url(https://www.pngjoy.com/pngl/69/1501951_stars-star-images-birthday-png-hd-png-download.png);
  } */

.container {
  overflow: clip;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dq6tqnvbh/image/upload/v1552834755/5a366dd97df550.5130252915135165055159.png">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum rhoncus orci nec iaculis. Cras tempor aliquam sem, id accumsan nibh mollis nec. Sed eget dui pulvinar, iaculis nibh vitae, molestie metus. Aliquam tortor leo, laoreet a felis
    quis, ultricies dignissim mauris. Etiam quis consectetur nibh. In sodales et ex at malesuada. Phasellus et arcu eleifend, interdum ex eu, bibendum magna.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
```

For better support you can rely on clip-path instead:

```css
.image {
  float: right;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  shape-outside: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dq6tqnvbh/image/upload/v1552834755/5a366dd97df550.5130252915135165055159.png);
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid green
}


.container {
  clip-path: inset(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dq6tqnvbh/image/upload/v1552834755/5a366dd97df550.5130252915135165055159.png">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum rhoncus orci nec iaculis. Cras tempor aliquam sem, id accumsan nibh mollis nec. Sed eget dui pulvinar, iaculis nibh vitae, molestie metus. Aliquam tortor leo, laoreet a felis
    quis, ultricies dignissim mauris. Etiam quis consectetur nibh. In sodales et ex at malesuada. Phasellus et arcu eleifend, interdum ex eu, bibendum magna.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Only thing is it seems like it pushes content down in the footer as if it was still there. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/kvzmw0sy/31/

Comment: I tried clearfixes and br tags with float clears